# Finding holes in a binary image

Tags: java, python, algorithm, binary-image

Assume we have following binary image

```
0010
0101
0101
0010
0100
1010
0100
0000
```

0 represents background pixels and 1 represents image pixels.As you can see there are two holes in this image.Is there a way to obtain the number of holes in this image using algorithms?(Java or Python but not Matlab)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Where are those holes?

Comment: Would you clearly explain what are holes?

Comment: your definition of a Hole is incomplete. what is the exact definition of a hole?

Comment: I believe a hole is an area of `0`s which is surrounded by `1`s.

Comment: Of course there is a way.  But this looks like homework in basic image processing. In which case, your question should include your own attempt to solve the question, and what problems you encountered in that solution.

Comment: It still should no matter if it’s homework or not. Please.

Comment: @Ssein Hole is a area surround by 1.In (2 nd row 3 rd column) and (3rd row 3rd column) we have two zeros which belong to same hole.And in 6th row 2nd column we have another hole with one zero.Total we have two holes.

Comment: I tried `Finding holes in a binary image -matlab` in my search engine, it seems to turn up interesting stuff. Try the same.

Comment: @RealSkeptic This isn't any homework.Just need an algorithm to get an idea.I am not requesting any code.

Comment: @OleV.V. Matlab has an inbuilt function to do this.What I need is the logic behind that functionn

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Hole is a area surround by 1.In (2 nd row 3 rd column) and (3rd row 3rd column) we have two zeros which belong to same hole.And in 6th row 2nd column we have another hole with one zero.Total we have two holes.

Comment: Are you after the exact logic Matlab uses, or just a reasonable algorithm to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some idea presented as code (and it might be not what you need).

The problem is, that i don't understand your example. Depending on the neighborhood-definition, there are different results possible.

- If you have a 8-neighborhood, all zeros are connected somehow (what does that mean about the surrounding 1's?).
- If you have a 4-neighborhood, each one surrounded by 4 1's represents a new hole

  - Of course you could postprocess this but the question is still unclear

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label

img = np.array([[0,0,1,0],
                [0,1,0,1],
                [0,1,0,1],
                [0,0,1,0],
                [0,1,0,0],
                [1,0,1,0],
                [0,1,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0]])

labels = label(img, connectivity=1, background=-1)  # conn=1 -> 4 neighbors
label_vals = np.unique(labels)                      # conn=2 -> 8 neighbors

counter = 0
for i in label_vals:
    indices = np.where(labels == i)
    if indices:
        if img[indices][0] == 0:
            print('hole: ', indices)
            counter += 1


print(img)
print(labels)
print(counter)
```

#### Output

```
('hole: ', (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])))
('hole: ', (array([0]), array([3])))
('hole: ', (array([1, 2]), array([2, 2])))
('hole: ', (array([3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]), array([3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3])))
('hole: ', (array([5]), array([1])))
[[0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[[ 1  1  2  3]
 [ 1  4  5  6]
 [ 1  4  5  6]
 [ 1  1  7  8]
 [ 1  9  8  8]
 [10 11 12  8]
 [ 8 13  8  8]
 [ 8  8  8  8]]
5
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a program on С# that calculates the Euler's number

We can calculate Euler's number according to this formula: Eu = (Q3 - Q1)/4;

```
Q1 - 00 or 00 or 01 or 10
     01    10    00    00
```

Q3 - 01 or 11 or 10 or 11
     11    10    11    10.

    So we go through the matrix, choosing 4 pixels at every step. 
The algorithm that I wrote counts the Euler's number by this formula.
Sorry for my English.
This is my github repository with full project: https://github.com/zeComedian/image-processing

```
public void BWEuler(int[,] image)
{
    int Q1 = 0;
    int Q3 = 0;

    int rows = image.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int columns = image.Length / rows;
    for (int i = 1; i < columns - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < rows - 1; j++)
        {
            if (image[i, j] == 0)
            {
                if ((image[i, j - 1] != 0) && (image[i - 1, j] != 0))
                {
                    Q3++;
                }
                if ((image[i - 1, j] != 0) && (image[i, j + 1] != 0))
                {
                    Q3++;
                }
                if ((image[i, j + 1] != 0) && (image[i + 1, j] != 0))
                {
                    Q3++;
                }
                if ((image[i + 1, j] != 0) && (image[i, j - 1] != 0))
                {
                    Q3++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((image[i, j - 1] != 1) && (image[i - 1, j] !=
        1))
                {
                    Q1++;
                }
                if ((image[i - 1, j] != 1) && (image[i, j + 1] !=
      1))
                {
                    Q1++;
                }
                if ((image[i, j + 1] != 1) && (image[i + 1, j] !=
       1))
                {
                    Q1++;
                }
                if ((image[i + 1, j] != 1) && (image[i, j - 1] !=
       1))
                {
                    Q1++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int Eu = ((Q3 - Q1) / 4);
    textBox3.Text = Eu.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(Eu);

}
```

Comment: Please provide more information, Like how this code works and how it fixes the problem?

Comment: We can calculate Euler's number according to this formula: Eu = (Q3 - Q1)/4;
Q1 - 0001 or 0010  or 0100 or 1000
                       
Q3 - 0111 or 1110 or 1011 or 1110
                        
The algorithm that I wrote counts the Euler's number by this formula

Comment: Better to add it to the post, not everyone going to read the comments, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using OpenCV connectedComponents function.

```
a=np.full((3,3), 1)
a[1,1]=0
print(a) >> [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
n,comp=cv2.connectedComponents(1-a) # 1-a, because components are considered white (non zero)
print(n-1) # number of holes
```